# Avoid inserting duplicate values in database with codeigniter active records

Tags: database, insert, duplicates

i am running a cronjob every 5mins on a file that is pulling in a xml feed, at the moment it is just adding that feed to the database, so i may get below.

```
title, this is a new title
title, this is another title
```

but the problem i have got is when the cron runs again i get below

```
title, this is a new title
title, this is another title
title, this is a new title
title, this is another title
```

and when it runs again

```
title, this is a new title
title, this is another title
title, this is a new title
title, this is another title
title, this is a new title
title, this is another title
```

And so on.....

i only want it to insert a records if their is not one already in the database with the same title so my cron job will keep running and when it notices a different title THEN it inserts it into the db.

I have tried lots of separate option such a not_like etc.

Can someone tell me the best way to do this???

Thankyou ;)

I managed to do it with the following but definitely not the best way todo it

```
    function addResults($data){

   $this->db->select('title');
       $this->db->from('articles');
       $this->db->where('title = ' . "'" . $data['title'] . "'");
       //$this->db->limit(1);
       $query=$this->db->get();
       echo $query->num_rows();
       if($query->num_rows()){

   }else{
        echo 'New Record ' . $data['title'];
        $this->db->set('date', 'NOW()', FALSE); 
            $this->db->insert('articles', $data);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I'm a little late for the party but here is a slightly better way to do it:

```
function addResults($data)
{
    $result = $this->db->get_where('articles', array('title ' => $data['title']));
    $inDatabase = (bool)$result->num_rows();

    if (!$inDatabase)
    {
        echo 'New Record ' . $data['title'];
        $this->db->set('date', 'NOW()', FALSE); 
        $this->db->insert('articles', $data);
    }
}
```